# Grails 3 - where's the DataSource.groovy and about plugins

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-3.0

So I downloaded Grails 3 M1 and created a project.  There's no DataSource.groovy, even after the MySQL driver was added to the dependencies - I thought maybe it will see the driver and know a DataSource.groovy is needed.

Secondly, plugins.  I found the Grails 3 plugin page (https://github.com/grails3-plugins)  How does one go about installing these?  Is there a new repository?  E.g. the newest Scaffolding plugin on Maven is from March 2014.  Will the older plugins still work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Grails 3 the configuration is now done with either a application.yml or application.groovy depending on what you prefer.

The configuration is no longer split up in multiple files like it has been done previously.

For more information:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/conf.html#environments

And for your second question. Most of the plugins should still work with the new Grails version. Updated versions will probably be available on the official plugins page soon.

Comment: The new file name is:  grails-app/conf/application.yml

Answer (score 3):

It is quite useful this [official GRAILS 3.x documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html) about config files no more present in release 3 and new files needed.

EDIT: I try to extend the answer as suggested:

"Some files that were previously created by Grails 2.x are no longer created. These have either been removed or an appropriate replacement added. The following table lists files no longer in use: (see table below)"

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14216397)

Comment: I extend the answer with details, but the whole page linked it is extremely interesting.

Comment: I complain about down vote, because the link is official documentation and is not true that is for older GRAILS version. It is really useful for migration from 2.x version.

Comment: The down-vote wasn't from me. The reason that link-only answers are discouraged is because links tend to go stale over time. So if it's better to include the essential parts in your answer, as you appear to have now done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Grails documentation for 3 still points to Grails 2.x

The DataSource.groovy no longer exists. I use application.yml for my datasource mods

For example:

```
environments:
    development:
          grails:
             mongo:
              host:localhost
              port:27017
              databaseName:zoom
```